# Writing data to an excel(CSV) file

Tags: java, servlets

I have created one servlet code. The main goal is to write data from a database to a csv file. In my code, the csv file gets downloaded successfully, but the file remains empty. The project contains javacsv.jar file. I don't have any clue why that is. Please shed some light on how I can achieve this. For a summary please read the points below:

- Access data from database table.
- Then write that data into the csv file with table format like < td >data here< / td> . [I want this format because I can format that data as per my requirements.]
- Please shed some light guys peace :) Refer this Servlet code below:

```java
public class excelServletFile extends HttpServlet {

    String name = "";
    String email = "";
    String eid = "Username";

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        try {
            String fileName = eid + "Data.csv";
            ServletContext context = getServletContext();
            String mimeType = context.getMimeType(fileName);
            if (mimeType == null) {
                mimeType = "application/octet-stream";
            }
            response.setContentType(mimeType);
            String headerKey = "Content-Disposition";
            String headerValue = String.format("attachment; filename=\"%s\"", fileName);
            response.setHeader(headerKey, headerValue);
            OutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();
            ConnectionClass cn = new ConnectionClass();
            Connection con = cn.connectDb();
            PreparedStatement ps;
            ResultSet rs;
            Charset cs = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
            Writer writer = new PrintWriter(System.out);
             writer.flush();
            writer.append("NAME");
            writer.append("EMAIL");
            ps = con.prepareStatement("select name,email from user");
            rs = ps.executeQuery();

            while (rs.next()) {
                name = rs.getString("name");
                email = rs.getString("email");
                PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
                out.println(name);
                out.println(email);
                writer.append(name);
                writer.append(email);

            }

            writer.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
}
```

Comment: Maybe `flush` the CsvWriter before you close it?

Comment: you mean to say i have to write csvOutput.endRecord(); outside the while loop ?

Comment: Well, no. What I meant was that `OutputStream` and `Writer` both implement `Flushable`, and so have a `flush` method which makes sure that any data that is still in buffer actually gets written to the stream target.

Comment: ok i got it. can you show me little example!

Comment: It's pretty simple. Either you call `csvOutput.flush();` just prior to `csvOutput.close();`, or if CsvWriter doesn't actually implement writer, you call `outStream.flush();`

Comment: @JeroenSteenbeeke as you said i have call csvOutput.flush(); but seems something missing. please go through that what i have done.

Comment: Well you might also need to call https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#flushBuffer()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
package servletProject;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/govinds")
public class CSVServlet extends HttpServlet {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(req, resp);
    }

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        FileWriter writer = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        Connection con = null;
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        try {
            String fileName = "D:/Data.csv";
            System.out.println(fileName);

            ConnectionClass cn = new ConnectionClass();
            con = cn.connectDb();

            System.out.println("fileName" + fileName);

            writer = new FileWriter(fileName);
            // Write the CSV file header
            CSVUtils.writeLine(writer, Arrays.asList("NAME", "email"));
            ps = con.prepareStatement("select firstName,email from employees");
            rs = ps.executeQuery();

            while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println(rs.getString("firstName"));
                CSVUtils.writeLine(writer, Arrays.asList(rs.getString("firstName"), rs.getString("email")));

            }

            writer.flush();
            writer.close();

            download(request, response);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                rs.close();
                ps.close();
                con.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }

    public void download(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        String filePath = "D:/Data.csv";
        File downloadFile = new File(filePath);
        FileInputStream inStream = new FileInputStream(downloadFile);

        // if you want to use a relative path to context root:
        String relativePath = getServletContext().getRealPath("");
        System.out.println("relativePath = " + relativePath);

        // obtains ServletContext
        ServletContext context = getServletContext();

        // gets MIME type of the file
        String mimeType = context.getMimeType(filePath);
        if (mimeType == null) {
            // set to binary type if MIME mapping not found
            mimeType = "application/octet-stream";
        }
        System.out.println("MIME type: " + mimeType);

        // modifies response
        response.setContentType(mimeType);
        response.setContentLength((int) downloadFile.length());

        // forces download
        String headerKey = "Content-Disposition";
        String headerValue = String.format("attachment; filename=\"%s\"", downloadFile.getName() + ".csv");
        response.setHeader(headerKey, headerValue);

        // obtains response's output stream
        OutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();

        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int bytesRead = -1;

        while ((bytesRead = inStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            outStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }

        inStream.close();
        outStream.close();
    }
}
```

// DB connection File

```
 public class ConnectionClass {


        public Connection connectDb() {

            Connection con=null;
            try {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  
                 con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/classicmodels","root","root");  
            }catch (Exception e) {
                con=null;
            }

            if(con!=null)
                System.out.println("connected");
            else
                System.out.println("not connected");

            return con;
        }
    }
```

//CSVUtil Files

```
package servletProject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.util.List;

public class CSVUtils {

    private static final char DEFAULT_SEPARATOR = ',';

    public static void writeLine(Writer w, List<String> values) throws IOException {
        writeLine(w, values, DEFAULT_SEPARATOR, ' ');
    }

    public static void writeLine(Writer w, List<String> values, char separators) throws IOException {
        writeLine(w, values, separators, ' ');
    }

    // https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180
    private static String followCVSformat(String value) {

        String result = value;
        if (result.contains("\"")) {
            result = result.replace("\"", "\"\"");
        }
        return result;

    }

    public static void writeLine(Writer w, List<String> values, char separators, char customQuote) throws IOException {

        boolean first = true;

        // default customQuote is empty

        if (separators == ' ') {
            separators = DEFAULT_SEPARATOR;
        }

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (String value : values) {
            if (!first) {
                sb.append(separators);
            }
            if (customQuote == ' ') {
                sb.append(followCVSformat(value));
            } else {
                sb.append(customQuote).append(followCVSformat(value)).append(customQuote);
            }

            first = false;
        }
        sb.append("\n");
        w.append(sb.toString());
    }

}
```

Comment: Add more details to your answer i.e : how does above code solved problem given in question . Simply posting code is not recommended, look here [how-to-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) .

Comment: yes if possible then please add more details in your answer. and CSVUtils is a java file or servlet ?

Comment: Thanks for helping but It is downloading only empty octate stream, not an excel file why? And there really that much of three file need for just a small functionality?? is it aslo possible with 1 servlet file and one class connection file.

Comment: @Govind Sharma can you do one more favour for me. the code is executing. but it is replacing the previous files. I'm trying for new file gets downloaded when the servlet page is load. each new time new file will gets downloaded. BTW there is dowloaded one file name it as "ExcelServletFile" at each time instead of this file i'm trying for the csv file will gets downloaded.

Comment: Bro please help me out of this. It's my humble request to you buddy.